# How do I make SQLite work with a JsonObject field?

Tags: c#, mysql, json, sqlite, asp.net-core

We are using EF Core MySQL (Pomelo) for a .NET Core project, and we have a xUnit test setup using an SQLite in-memory database. We're configuring a JSON column that works fine in MySQL but doesn't work in our tests. We've tried adding a ValueConverter, as you can see below, during testing to make SQLite treat the JsonObject as a string instead, but it seems that gets ignored completely. We have also tried to force the column type to "varchar(MAX)".

```
class FooBar
{
  [Column(TypeName = "json")]
  public JsonObject<Dictionary<string, object>> Foo { get; set; }
}

class FooBarDbContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<FooBar> FooBars { get; set; }
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
  {
    // only during testing.
    builder.Entity<FooBar>().Property(fooBar => fooBar.Foo).HasConversion(
      v => v.ToString(),
      v => new JsonObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(v)).HasColumnType("varchar(MAX)");
  }
}
```

How do I make SQLite work with a JsonObject field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dan, all things considered, my considered recommendation to you would be that you use *MySQL* for your unit-tests, if that is what you are using in production.  Otherwise, you run into several significant dangers:

- The test situation does not match production – MySQL and SQLite are very considerably different in their handling of data types.
- The source-code becomes littered with code that exists only to handle the "impedance mismatch" between the two database types, *and* between the test and the production situation.
- "What you test," and what tests correctly, "is the test-case code."  Problems in the production case therefore slip through and are not unearthed until – *(ick ...)* – production deployment.

Developers *can* deploy MySQL servers on their own laptops, with appropriate test data inside, with a server-IP of `127.0.0.1`. And so, in this situation, this is what I advise you to do (instead).

Comment: I agree with this advice and recommend using Docker to run MySQL (instead of installing the full-blown server on development machines), e.g., with `docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:5.7`

Comment: This really good input, we've decided to mock the database during unit testing since that makes it a proper unit test for our case. Then we'll use MySQL for integration tests.

Comment: Just seeing this while searching on a similar question. Using docker mysql is about a billion times slower than in memory. When you have a large enough team and an automated CI pipeline you can't wait an hour for unit tests to run. You should have a smaller number of Acceptance/Integration tests for that case.